# Printing points inside a page with border

Tags: exam, points

I am preparing an exam and all the pages have borders, except my front page. Now I would like to print points after the question, but despite various attempts, the points are been printed in the margin or cannot been seen. I would appreciate any help in this regard. Here is code.

```
\documentclass[addpoints, 12pt]{exam}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm,amssymb,amsfonts}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{fancybox}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[vmargin={10mm,20mm},hmargin={10mm,10mm}]{geometry}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{setspace}
\pagestyle{plain}
\begin{document}
\fancypage{\setlength{\fboxsep}{0pt}\fbox}{}

\qformat{\textbf{Q \thequestion}\hfill}
\begin{questions}
    \pointsdroppedatright
    \bracketedpoints

    \question
    \begin{parts}
        \part[2] Use the formula for $\cos{(A+B)}$ and $\cos{(A-B)}$ to show that $$\cos{(A+B)}+\cos{(A-B)} \equiv 2\cos{A}\cos{B}.$$
        \droppoints
        \fillwithdottedlines{1.5in}
        \part[3] Hence show that $$\cos{P}+\cos{Q} \equiv 2\cos\left( \frac{P+Q}{2}\right)\cos{\left( \frac{P-Q}{2}\right) }.$$

        \fillwithdottedlines{\stretch{1}}
        %   \part[3] Deduce that $$\frac{\cos{4x}+\cos{2x}}{2\cos{3x}} \equiv \cos{x}.$$
        %   \droppoints
        %   \fillwithdottedlines{1.5in}
    \end{parts}
    \droptotalpoints

    \newpage
    \question
    \begin{parts}
        \part[2] new part
        \droppoints

        \part[4] another part
        \droppoints
    \end{parts}
    \droptotalpoints

\end{questions}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Not a real solution, but you could do `\let\droptotalpointsBAK\droptotalpoints\def\droptotalpoints{\hfill\llap{\droptotalpointsBAK}\hspace*{2cm}}` as a work around.

Comment: @Skillmon, where should I place place this line?

Comment: Just before `\begin{document}`, but I guess I'm a bit late :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can shift the points using `\setlength{\rightpointsmargin}{}`, and increase the page border using `\fancypage{\setlength{\fboxsep}{5pt}\fbox}{}`. I also changed the `\totalformat` to be more similar to `\qformat` and removed unrelated packages.

Here is the full code.

```
\documentclass[addpoints, 12pt]{exam}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm,amssymb,amsfonts}
\usepackage{fancybox}
\usepackage[vmargin={10mm,20mm},hmargin={10mm,10mm}]{geometry}
\pagestyle{plain}

\qformat{\textbf{Q\,\thequestion}\hfill}
\totalformat{Total for Q\,\thequestion: [\totalpoints]}
\pointsdroppedatright
\bracketedpoints
\setlength{\rightpointsmargin}{2.65cm}
\fancypage{\setlength{\fboxsep}{5pt}\fbox}{}

\begin{document}
\begin{questions}

    \question
    \begin{parts}
        \part[2] Use the formula for $\cos{(A+B)}$ and $\cos{(A-B)}$ to show that $$\cos{(A+B)}+\cos{(A-B)} \equiv 2\cos{A}\cos{B}.$$
        \droppoints
        \fillwithdottedlines{1.5in}
        \part[3] Hence show that $$\cos{P}+\cos{Q} \equiv 2\cos\left( \frac{P+Q}{2}\right)\cos{\left( \frac{P-Q}{2}\right) }.$$

        \fillwithdottedlines{\stretch{1}}
    \end{parts}
    \droptotalpoints

    \newpage
    \question
    \begin{parts}
        \part[2] new part
        \droppoints

        \part[4] another part
        \droppoints
    \end{parts}
    \droptotalpoints

\end{questions}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

The documentation on this package explains this behaviour. Do `\setlength{\rightpointsmargin}{somelength}` to change spacing between the points and the right border of the document. See section 4.3.10 [here](http://www-math.mit.edu/~psh/exam/examdoc.pdf)